# moving my site collection from root to a new managed path

Tags: 2013, administration, central-administration, backup, restore

I am working on a Team site collection inside SharePoint enterprise server 2013. and the publishing infrastructure site collection and site features are enable. now i want to move the site collection from being on the root to be under a new managed path.

The site collection i want to move have the following properties:-

1. It is defined on the root `http://servername/`
2. It have one direct sub-site `http://servername/Dept/`
3. the above sub-site have another sub-site `http://servername/Dept/DeptA`

now i want to move the site collection to be under different url which is `http://servername/Area/<current site collection>`... where "Area" will be a Explicit managed path.

so i am planning to do the following to move the site collection from being on the root to its new URL.

1. back up the current site collection using BackUp-SPSite

   Backup-SPSite http://servername/ -Path C:\Backup\A.bak
2. remove the current site collection permanently
3. create the new managed path named "Area"
4. Restore the site collection on the new url

   Restore-SPSite http://servername/Area/A -Path C:\Backup\A.bak

so are the above 4 steps valid ? and could i result in having duplicate GUIDs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Above scenario should work, as you are deleting the existing site collection then you will not see the Duplicate GUID problem.

You may need to refresh the config db, in order to update the record ( very less chances)

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase | where {$_.Name -eq "DatabaseName"}
$db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()
```

Comment: not sure about the RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase what will it do exactly? second question if you were in my place which approach you will follow, will you consider the same appraoch as mine ?

Comment: if i am your situation, yes i will. I did this before and it worked well. Refresh update the Config database with new information, like you are creating the site on managed path...it will update it and also remove the deleted site from his list.

Comment: so if i follow this approach should i be safe against any GUID conflicts for new site collections?

Comment: Should be safe, Again as good SharePoint admin always test the scenario in lower environment.

Comment: But should i create an empty site collection at "_http://servername/Area/A_" before doing the "_Restore-SPSite http://servername/Area/A -Path C:\Backup\A.bak_" ? or the restore will automatically create the site collection for me?

Comment: second question is it straightforward to remove a site collection which is defined on the root ?

Comment: its upto you, if you want you can create in advance then use the -force parameter in your command otherwise it will create one

Comment: but is there a recommended way to do the Restore? i mean to already create a site collection in advance or not ?second question is there any special things i need to do when deleting a root site collection ?